# Wireguard Client to Client issues

Tags: networking, vpn, wireguard

Server: Ubuntu

- Wireguard server all clients connect to
- Runs SMB share: all clients can access when the VPN is connected
- Clients can ping eachother

Client a: Windows Server 2022

- Firewall: `Allow 192.168.6.0/24`
- IIS `*:80`

  - Works locally, works on VPN Server (wget), does not work on client b. Client b can access IIS over the server's public IP address, not the VPN address
- SQL Server

  - configured to allow remote connections, client b can't access it over VPN ip.

Client b: Windows 11

- Can ping client a, can't access IIS, can't access SQL Server

Added public IP address of client b to firewall of client a, after that, I can connect to SQL server over the public IP address, not the VPN IP.

Clients all have `AllowedIPs = 192.168.6.0/24` in their config

Any advice welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, I needed these `PostUp` and `PostDown` rules in my `wg0.conf` to make it work.

````
PostUp =   iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -I FORWARD 1 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 192.168.6.0/24 -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -j ACCEPT;   iptables -D FORWARD -o wg0 -j ACCEPT; iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s 192.168.6.0/24 -o enp4s0 -j MASQUERADE```
````